# Iphone devolpement Dynamic Flickr Rss graber

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image, uiview

I am trying to adapt http://kosmaczewski.net/2009/03/08/asynchronous-loading-of-images-in-a-uitableview/ to load a specific flickr feed but at the moment when I put in a flick rss feed in definations.h  it wont load the images past the thumbnail view

```
//
//  Definitions.h
//  AsyncTable
//
//  Created by Adrian on 3/8/09.
//  Copyright 2009 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

// URL of the public Flickr RSS feed
#define NEWS_FEED_URL @"http://api.flickr.com/services/somekind of feed here"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem You just have to edit the XML parser a bit